# Client not syncing messages; mod_carboncopy

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I've had a prosody running trunk for about a year and haven't had any issues.

I've been testing ejabberd 18.12 and completed a transfer with
`ejabberdctl import_prosody`

on a "migrated" prosody directory with `prosody-migrator`

Now, carbon copy when messaging others and messaging yourself (*bob@domain* messaging *bob@domain*) doesn't seem to work

**I'm expecting when I send a message on Conversations, Gajim and Converse.js should also see that sent message. I'm also expecting to see messages I send myself to myself**

I've been testing between gajim-nightly, Conversations Beta and converse.js

- Conversations reports `XEP-0280` Message Carbons are available
- Gajim-nightly enable_message_carbons is activated

Ejabberd while running in foreground  doesn't give any information.

In ejabberd, `mod_carboncopy: {}` should be shown as enabled.

Disabling a account and re-enabling (and triggering MAM) causes these messages to show up.
Some tests:

- bob@domain (Conversations Beta) -> bob@domain:

  - shows up on Gajim but not Converse.js (loads with MAM following account disable / enable)
- bob@domain (Gajim) -> bob@domain:

  - Neither receive, both (Converse, Conversations) load with MAM following account disable / enable
- bob@domain (Converse) -> bob@domain:

  - Shows up on Gajim but not Conversations (loads with MAM following account disable / enable)
- bob@domain (Conversation) -> **anotheruser**@domain:

  - Message received by anotheruser@domain
  - Neither Conversations nor Converse see it (MAM load with account disable / enable syncs the message for both)
- bob@domain (Converse) -> anotheruser@domain

  - Message received by anotheruser@domain
  - Neither Conversations nor Gajim see it (MAM load with account disable / enable syncs the message for both)
- bob@domain (Gajim) -> anotheruser@domain

  - Message received by anotheruser@domain
  - Neither Conversations nor Converse see it (MAM load with account disable / enable syncs the message for both)

tldr; mod_mam is working fine but mod_carboncopy doesn't.

Prosody config

https://paste.debian.net/plainh/0d11e53a

Ejabberd config

https://paste.debian.net/plainh/e90f8952

additional ejabberd config file

https://paste.debian.net/plainh/acddd817

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in 18.12

Apparently should be fixed in 18.12.1

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2719

> Yes, the regression has been fixed already. Sorry for the inconvenience.